# How to Index a JOIN result of two or more tables in order to improve the performance in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing

I am new to indexing and gone through the basics of indexing. I can find a default clustered index for the primary key constraint within the indexes part of the corresponding table, but after creating a foreign key constraint i can't find any.

Now i've a requirement in which indexing should be implemented to improve performance. I've read about **indexing the foreign key** in order to improve the performance of a **JOIN result**.

**Do i need to add the foreign key column to an additional non-clustered index or the foreign key has a default indexing?**

How can i effectively implement indexing if my **SQL table structure** is as follows and i've a **JOIN query** with **WHERE clause** using **t1_col3**

```
               table1                       table2
               ------                       ------
               t1_col1(pk)                  t2_col1(pk)
               t1_col2                      t2_col2
               t1_col3                      t2_col3
               t1_col4                      t2_col4
               t2_col1(FK)
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific - How many rows are being returned?  Also, why is the existing query slow? - do you have an execution plan?

Comment: I've a table which will get updated on daily basis and a query to fetch all at a time. Since i am expecting large number of records i don't think the current execution plan makes any sense.

Comment: If you have access to it, try to use Database Engine Tuning Advisor with your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a query plan, an actual query, or details about how your data are distributed it is not possible to make a concrete recommendation, but here are a few things to keep in mind.

1. Creating a foreign key does not automatically create an index on the foreign key column. It is simply a constraint.
2. Because joins between tables frequently involve foreign key columns, and because SQL Server will need to check the foreign key column regularly in order to enforce the constraint, it is usually a good idea to place an index on the foreign key column.
3. With what little you've described, your query has a criterion against the t1_col3 column - it will use that column to filter the values in table1; it *might* (it really depends on the query plan, and that's dependent on the distribution of data in the tables and other criteria and operations in the query) be a good idea to place an index on t1_col3.

For the third point, the usefulness of the index will depend a lot on the specific iterator/operator the query engine uses to implement a join between the two tables, and which table drives the join.

Any further information you can provide - the query, a query plan, number of rows - will help us provide a more specific answer.

Comment: @Mathew Burr, Thanks for a detailed explanation...Now i got an idea on how to approach indexing..